# Identity for modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a concruence subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $k$ an integer and $f, g \in M_k(\Gamma)$.

We want to show that for $M \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})⁺$ and $M \Gamma M^{-1} \subset SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $:

$ [\bar{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}: \bar{\Gamma}] = [\bar{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}:M \Gamma M^{-1}]$

So we want to show that the index for those two subgroups is the same. I think it is clear to me why $M \Gamma M^{-1}$ is a subgroup. But how does one compare these indices? By comparing the cosets and showing two inequalities or is there another trick.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.